# Adding a separator between found results by sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a text file like this for example:

```
test.txt:
Hello my name is test
Well my name will be test
Hello Hello test
Hello my name already is test
```

Now I want to get everything between every 'Hello' and 'test'. This works for me:

`cat test.txt | sed --quiet '/Hello/,/test/p'`

It gives the following output:

```
Hello my name is test
Hello Hello test
Hello my name already is test
```

Would it be possible to separate my findings like this:

```
Hello my name is test;
Hello Hello test;
Hello my name already is test;
```

The delimiter does not have to be ';' any other character will work just fine.

Comment: Try: `sed 's/Hello.*test/&;/' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but, assuming you want lines that start with `Hello` and to add a semi colon at the end, you can try;

```
$ sed -n '/^Hello/{s/$/;/p}' input_file
Hello my name is test;
Hello Hello test;
Hello my name already is test;
```

Comment: Or perhaps `sed 's/^Hello.*/&;/p;d' file`